# Make "cut" command work only when text is selected

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

The default behaviour of `Ctrl+X` in VSCode in the absence of selected text is to cut the current line. I would like to configure VSCode so that `Ctrl+X` only works if text is selected. I have tried adding the following to my `keybindings.json` file

```
[
// Cut only when selection
{
    "key": "ctrl+x",
    "command": "-editor.action.clipboardCutAction"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+x",
    "command": "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
    "when": "editorHasSelection",
},
]
```

but it does not seem to take effect. What is the correct way to make `Ctrl+X` work only if text is selected?

Comment: use the keyboard debugging to see what happens when you press the key binding

Comment: Hi @rioV8, thank you for your comment. This does not specify the action that is executed for `Ctrl+X`, even though it specifies it for other keybindings. For `Ctrl+X` it says `[KeybindingService]: \ From 2 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.` without specifying the specific action.

Comment: Thank you, I realized this meant that even though there are no commands bound to `Ctrl+X`, VSCode still cuts the current line by default. I fixed it by binding it to something else that does nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the relatively unknown command `noop` (no operation) here to make this a little better:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+x",         // needs to go before the next command
    "command": "noop"        // 'noop' FTW, no 'when' clause necessary
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+x",         // needs to go after the previous
    "command": "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @rioV8's suggestion to [keyboard troubleshootting functionality](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings), I realized that even though `Ctrl+X` was not bound to any command, the default action by VSCode was to still cut the current line.

I have fixed this by binding `Ctrl+X` to something that does nothing when no text is selected.

```
[
{
    "key": "ctrl+x",
    "command": "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection",
},

{
    "key": "ctrl+x",
    "command": "cancelSelection",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection",
},
]
```